# Max-Heapify Algorithm Task

Tags: algorithm, heap

Let A[1...9] = 3 9 5 4 8 6 11 7 2 be an array consisting of 9 numbers. Illustrate how A looks like after executing the code Max - Heapify (A, 4, 9), Max-Heapify(A,3,9), Max-Heapify(A,2,9), Max-Heapify(A,1,9).

Why is may Array wrong?

I draw a heap tree [image]

After then I tried to do it

Heapify (A, 4, 9) value 4 and 2 exchange
3 9 5 2 8 6 11 7 4 -> I sorted 3 9 5 7 8 6 11 2 4

Max-Heapify(A,3,9) -> value 5 and 4 exchange

3 9 4 7 8 6 11 2 5 -> I sorted 3 9 11 7 8 6 4 2 5 -> 11 9 3 7 8 6 4 2 5

Max-Heapify(A,2,9) -> value 11 and 9 exchange

11 9 6 7 8 3 4 2 5

Max-Heapify(A,1,9) -> value 11 and 5
5 9 6 7 8 3 4 2 11 -> How do I sort it do I start from the parent node or from bottom up? Is there any hints to solve this problem in general in an array instead of drawing the heap tree?

SOLUTION: 11 9 6 7 8 3 5 4 2

Comment: You need to provide some additional details.  Does your array indexing start at zero or at one?  Do you have two functions `Heapify` and `Max-Heapify`, or just one and you're being sloppy about writing your question?  What, specifically, are the arguments for your functions?

Comment: Oh sorry it starts from 1. I thinks its only Max-Heapify. Because above is the question which was in the midterm.

Comment: If it was on the midterm I'm guessing it's consistent with what your instructor told you in class, but since I didn't sit in on your class I still have no idea what the arguments are.  I'm willing to assume `A` is your array, but what is `Max-Heapify(A, 4, 9)` supposed to do with the numbers 4 and 9?

Comment: index 1 2 3 4 5 6  7  8  9 
value 3 9 5 4 8 6 11 7 2
Max-Heapify(Array, index4, index9) at this pos I have to exchange the value of the index 4 with index 9

Comment: You're still not getting it - what does the number 4 mean when used as the second argument?  Ditto for the number 9 as the third argument.

Comment: Max-Heapify(A, i, n) = A[i], A[Left(i)], A[Right(i)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you interpret MaxHeapify as doing something else than it is supposed to do. For example, you write:

> `Heapify (A, 4, 9)` value 4 and 2 exchange

No. The children of the value at index 4 are at index 8 and 9. To know where a node's children are located, double the index and add 0 or 1. The 7 at (index 8) is greater than its parent at index 4, so the exchange is between values 4 and 7. The result:

```
3 9 5 7 8 6 11 4 2
      *        * *
```

Note that after this exchange, both the children of the node at index 4 are smaller.

`Heapify (A, 3, 9)` will compare the value at index 3 (5) with its children at indices 6 and 7. The values there are 6 and 11: 11 must bubble up:

```
3 9 11 7 8 6 5 4 2
     *     * *
```

`Heapify (A, 2, 9)` will compare the value at index 2 (9) with its children at indices 4 and 5: values 7 and 8: that's OK as it is; no change:

```
3 9 11 7 8 6 5 4 2
  *    * *
```

`Heapify (A, 1, 9)` will compare the value at index 1 (3) with its children at indices 2 and 3: values 9 and 11: 11 must bubble up:

```
11 9 3 7 8 6 5 4 2
*  * *
```

At this point the heap is completely heapified: for each node you now have that its value is greater (or equal) than the values of its children. That's all a heap is. A heap is not a sorted array. To get the values in descending order, you need to pop elements from the top of the heap according to the *extract* algorithm: take out the front element, put the tail element there instead, make the array 1 element shorter, and sift down the front value into the heap (through exchanges) until the heap property is restored.

You can read about all functions related to the heap structure, at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).